# Change author base slug to user role

Tags: author, slug

My goal is simple, to change authot base role to user role.

**For example:**

**admin**:
wwww.mysite.com/**admin**/username

**editor**:
www.mysite.com/**editor**/username

**default looks like this to any user**:
www.mysite.com/**author**/username

I couldn't find any examples online. **How to achieve this?**

Answer (score 1):

I think the plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/edit-author-slug/ does exactly what you need.